# Is this quadratic function monotonically increasing?

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, monotone-functions

> Given vector $x'$ and positive definite matrix $W$, let $$ f(x) := (x-x')^TW(x-x') $$ Show that $f$ is monotonically increasing, i.e. if $y-x' > x-x'$ component-wise, then $f(y) > f(x)$.

---

I do not know how to approach this. I do not know how to use the positive definiteness of $W$.

Comment: What order relation are you using for the vectors?

Comment: @VanTom From the tag description itself: "a monotonic function (or monotone function) is a function between ordered sets that preserves or reverses the given order."

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo $(x-x')^T\,(x-x')$ would be a valid ordering parameter for the vectors $x$? So the problem would be to show that a vector more distant of $x'$ would result in a higher value of $f(x)$?

Comment: I have edit my question.

Comment: @VanTom How are you comparing the vectors? By their L2-norms?

Comment: @DanielCunha component-wise

Comment: @VanTom Is $W$ real and symmetric? Also, shouldn't the comparison be made with absolute values?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true if $y \geq x$ is taken to be a componentwise condition -- at least not without further restrictions
A simple counterexample is with $x' = 0$,
$$
W = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}, \\~\\
x = (-1, -1), \\~\\
y = (0, 0),
$$
then $y \geq x$ and $x^T W x = 2$ but $y^T W y = 0$.

Or in case you are worried about the use of vectors with negative entries in the previous example, here is one in which $x, y \geq 0$. Take $ W = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, $x = (1, 0)$ and $y = (4/3, 1)$.

Answer (score 0):

As showed by Rammus, many more conditions are needed.
In fact, because f is differentiable, for it to be monotonically increasing, its derivative must also be nonnegative, that is:
$\nabla f(x) \ge 0$ for all vector $x$ in $range(f)$.
And this is also a sufficient condition.
So I guess by now you can find the needed conditions for your function $f$.

Comment: How do I differentiate $f$ in this case?

Comment: Manually, as it should be by definition. If I'm not mistaken, $\nabla F (x) = 2Ax$ for $F(x)=x^{T}Ax$.